# cmd: unexpected error with @pause and path>txt

Tags: windows, time, batch-file, cmd

I am coding a batch file. Here is a sample:

```
if exist rootsys.txt del rootsys.txt
if %lang%==1 (
if %bit%==32 echo C:\Program Files\path\to\the dir>rootsys.txt
if %bit%==64 echo C:\Program Files(x86)\path\to\the dir>rootsys.txt
goto :waset
)
```

This goes on for six times (so `if %lang%==2` etc... to `if %lang%==6`.)

So, what it does, the user puts something in, like '6', so it will do the thing for the sixth.

But, whenever i try this, it ends up with `\the was unexpected at this time`.
So, i tried debugging with `@echo on`. Seemed that it gave me the error at `if exist rootsys.txt del rootsys.txt`. How can that happen?!

I am 110% sure i do not mention `the`(actually i use this as a sample, it has another name) nowhere else in my batch file. Can anyone help me? I am really stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enclose the `C:\Program Files\path\to\the dir`  string with `"`

Comment: if i would `set /p path=<rootsys.txt`, will it also come out with quotes?

Comment: no, the set command takes everything the right of the equal character and assigns it to the variable so no quotes are needed

Comment: btw: it works however. thanks. i don't need an answer anymore to the question above